# Ternary in WHERE condition (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, ternary

MySQL (5.7.x): Is there anyway to do a ternary argument in WHERE conditions?

I'm trying to run a AND clause based on the value of the select:

```sql
    SELECT DISTINCT p.user_id, eml.template, eml.subject
        FROM order_lines ol, email_template eml
        JOIN user p ON ol.user_id = p.user_od
        WHERE ol.status in (9.2, 10)
        -- This line here
            AND eml.name = (ol.status = 10 'SurveyOne' ? 'SurveyTwo')
```

I need to get user_id, and conditional row from eml based on ol.status value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, the ternary operator is the `IF()` function.

```
AND eml.name = IF(ol.status = 10, 'SurveyOne', 'SurveyTwo')
```

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in SQL, we try to keep conditional logic out of `where` clauses (it can be harder to follow than simple logic).

So, consider:

```
WHERE (ol.status = 10 and eml.name = 'SurveyOne') or
      (ol.status = 9.2 and eml.name = 'SurveyTwo')
```

Note:  The constant "9.2" is suspicious.  You need to be very careful when you have numbers with decimal points and you are doing comparisons using `=`.

In some databases (but not MySQL), this can be simplified to:

```
WHERE (ol.status, eml.name) in ( (10, 'SurveyOne', (9.2, 'SurveyTwo') )
```